# Por qué se calcula mal la fecha con Carbon en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

tengo en mi código una variable para que me entregue la fecha del día de hoy...

Para ello uso Carbon, de laravel, el código es este

```
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('es');
```

Pero por alguna razón, me entrega el mes anterior, quiero decir, en lugar de darme la fecha de hoy "06-04-2023" me entrega "06-03-2023"

Si alguien puede ayudarme con esto, sería genial!

Comment: Desconozco el lenguaje, pero se me ocurre (por el tipo de "error") que tal vez maneje los meses del "0" al "11", puedes verificarlo creando una fecha tipo "24/12/2023" e imprimirla, si da error...

Answer (score 0):

Me falta algo de información sobre tu pregunta, por lo que quizás alguno de los puntos que describo estén revisados.

Lo primero de todo, asegúrate que el formato de fecha que estás imprimiendo sea correcto. Por ejemplo, para imprimir la fecha de hoy con formato día/mes/año deberías poner:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->locale('es');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

También, podría tratarse de un problema de configuración del Hosting, para comprobarlo te recomiendo subir un archivo PHP a public con el siguiente código:

```
<?php
echo date('d/m/Y');
```

Con esto, estarás ejecutando PHP sin pasar por tu proyecto de Laravel, por lo que si utilizando esto la fecha también es incorrecta y detectarás que el problema está en la configuración del servidor.

En caso de que todo lo anterior esté configurado correctamente, podría tratarse de un problema en la configuración de Laravel. En config/app.php, revisa que el timezone añadido sea correcto.

Si estos puntos no resuelven tu duda te recomendaría añadir algo más de info como:

- Versión de PHP.
- Versión de Laravel.
- Línea de cómo pides la info y cómo se imprime.